# Gradle: find and build all projects in folder

Tags: gradle, build

I have a folder with a lot of projects inside it (too much to manually write build files for them)

The projects are mostly in a flat layout:

```
root
    -project 1
    -project 2
    -project 3
    -project 4
    -project 5
    (    -project 5.1)
```

But can be nested as shown above, and I need to account for this.

Ideally the following should happen:

- I can run `user@user:/root gradle build` and every project in the directory shoudl be built as long as it contains a gradle build file
- if a build fails just continue with the next one

How can I make this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a working solution:

```
def flist = []
// change to you workspace name
new File('./Workspace').eachDir {
    //blacklist any folders you want
    if (it.name !='.gradle' && it.name != 'master' && it.name!= 'Build-All') { 
        flist << it.name 
    }   
}

// build task objects

flist.each { folder ->
    task "${folder}"(type: GradleBuild) {
        buildFile = "./Workspace/"+ folder + "/build.gradle"
        dir = './' + folder
        tasks = ['build']
    }
}
// create super task
task (all, dependsOn: flist) {
}
```

You need to invoke it as such in the root directory: `gradle :all --continue` this has the benefit that any failing project builds will not halt the other builds.

Another bonus is that gradle gives a neat report about all failing builds.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one-liner (not tested):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && gradle build || true" \;
```

Or, more verbose:

```
dirs=($(find . -type d))
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    cd "$dir"
    gradle build || true
done
```